# HDFS Browsing Permission Denied While creating a directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm new to hadoop. I have finished installing hadoop on my ubuntu and open the localhost view. But when I try to create a directory in Browsing HDFS I got the following error `Permission denied: user=dr.who, access=WRITE, inode="/":hdusr:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x`

I'm also attaching the screenshot
[Hadoop_Screenhot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqKpJ.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a directory as root, you need to be the superuser. The superuser, is the linux user who is running the namenode processes - generally "hdfs", but it looks like its hduser on your setup.

Try:

```
sudo -u hduser hadoop fs -mkdir /test
```

Or, assuming Kerberos is not enabled on your cluster:

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=hduser
hadoop fs -mkdir /test
```

Comment: Great It works. But I don't how do I transfer my CSV file from Desktop to this folder test.
I can see the test folder on hdfs view

Comment: sudo -u hduser hadoop fs -put /local/file /file/or/folder/on/hdfs